# Angle corners of border in a view

Tags: swiftui

Im trying to angle the corners of a border in swiftUI like so: [image]

This would be the bottom border(the red shape) of a text view for example.

Being new to swiftui im unsure of the best way to do this. Is it best to draw it as a path within a `Shape` or are there better options?

Comment: There's no pure SwiftUI way to do this, so you're right, you'll need to draw it as a path within a shape.

Comment: There is some api for the thing you want, but it is unclear what you looking for, where is text in your photo? and what is that black background? or what is that mesh? so unclear things!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Struct I made to create beveled borders as a Shape.
Change `offset` to increase bevel size, change the code to handle top or bottom only. It's pretty straightforward.

**Code**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Bevel: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let offset: CGFloat = 10
    
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + offset, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - offset, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + offset))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY - offset))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - offset, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + offset, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY - offset))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY + offset))
    
        return path
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Button {
    
    } label: {
        Text("Start")
    }
    .padding()
    .foregroundColor(Color("ForegroundColor"))
    .background(
        Bevel()
        .fill(Color("AccentColor"))
    )
```

**Result**

[image: Start Button]